# Devexpress GridView Export xlsx to a folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I use devexpress gridview export to export excel to a folder, I am able to export the excel file but i have no idea how to export the excel file to a specific folder. Can anyone guide me on this?

For example this is the code to export my gridview xlsx and it works fine

```
exportFeedbackGrid.WriteXlsToResponse()
```

and i wanted my xlsx file to export to the e:\filelocation, how can i achieve this?

```
<dx:ASPxGridViewExporter GridViewID="FeedbackGrid" ID="exportFeedbackGrid" OnLoad="ExportTo"  runat ="server"></dx:ASPxGridViewExporter>

 Public Sub ExportTo(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim stream As Stream = New FileStream("e:\filelocation", FileMode.Create)
        exportFeedbackGrid.WriteXlsToResponse()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide example how current Excel export looks like? Are you want to export to specified folder inside the server?

Comment: yes, i have edited the description.

Comment: Is that `exportFeedbackGrid` an `ASPxGridView` or `ASPxGridViewExporter` control? I found that you can save XLS file to disk with `ASPxGridViewExporter`, besides using `WriteXlsToResponse()` method (but not for client-side folders, only server-side folders supported).

Comment: that is ASPxGridViewExporter's ID(edited the post) . Sorry but could you provide sample for that so that i can learn from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed `exportFeedbackGrid` is an `ASPxGridViewExporter` control, you may use standard I/O methods provided by `System.IO` namespace to handle output from grid exporter control before executing `WriteXlsToResponse()` method, as given in example below:

```
Public Sub ExportTo(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' write to specified folder
    Using ms As New MemoryStream()
        exportFeedbackGrid.WriteXls(ms)
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

        Using stream As New FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/path/to/file/location/example.xls"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
            ms.WriteTo(stream)
        End Using
    End Using

    ' write as response
    exportFeedbackGrid.WriteXlsToResponse()
End Sub
```

**Notes:**

1. The specified server's folder path must have enabled write access permission (i.e. permission to create files).
2. If you experiencing problems when assigning direct file path, consider using IIS virtual directory (also with enabled write permission to the physical path).

Reference:

[ASPxGridViewExporter - How to save a file to a disk](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/aspxgridviewexporter-how-to-save-a-file-to-a-disk-t297497)

Comment: sorry for extremely late reply, this works on my code, thanks!                                                                                                                   
        Using stream1 As New FileStream("C:\New folder\MonthlyReport.xls", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

            dt.WriteXls(stream1)

        End Using

Comment: that works perfectly on devexpress. Do you have any idea on this?               https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51604336/vb-net-console-application-export-xlsx-to-specific-folder